# Is there a way I can get the media ID for associated media on an IG story's insights though meta graph API?

Tags: instagram-graph-api

if a reel is shared on a story, can I get that reel's media ID through meta graph API

Currently, it shares all insights like exits, impressions, and reach but does not share the source media ID of the reel.

While I'm able to get the entire story in the form of an MP4, I would like to access the media ID of the source reel that was shared on the story